# Index parameterization in Cypher REST query

Tags: rest, lucene, neo4j, cypher

I have this query which works well but without parametrization in index. emp is an index, and NUM_OFC_CA is an emp number (key in emp index), to simplify i want to return NME_CA.

```
curl -X POST http://xyzhost:7474/db/data/ext/CypherPlugin/graphdb/execute_query -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary '{
    "query": "START ca=node:emp(\"NUM_OFC_CA: 997015\") RETURN distinct ca.NME_CA as `CA Name`",
    "params": {
     }
}'
```

How can i parametrize above REST query, i have tried something like this:

```
curl -X POST http://xyzhost:7474/db/data/ext/CypherPlugin/graphdb/execute_query -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary '{
    "query": "START ca=node:emp(\"NUM_OFC_CA: {num_ofc_ca}\") RETURN distinct ca.NME_CA as `CAName`",
    "params": {
        "num_ofc_ca": "997015"
    }
}'
```

I am getting this error:

```
{
  "message" : "org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse 'NUM_OFC_CA: {num_ofc_ca}': Encountered \" \"}\" \"} \"\" at line 1, column 23.\nWas expecting one of:\n    \"TO\" ...\n    <RANGEEX_QUOTED> ...\n    <RANGEEX_GOOP> ...\n    ",
  "exception" : "BadInputException",
  "stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.server.plugin.cypher.CypherPlugin.executeScript(CypherPlugin.java:61)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginMethod.invoke(PluginMethod.java:57)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:168)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:300)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:122)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)" ]
}
```

Need help to resolve this issue.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a plain index query, the [syntax](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-start.html#start-node-by-index-lookup) is as follows:

```
curl -X POST http://<host>:7474/db/data/ext/CypherPlugin/graphdb/execute_query -H "Content-Type: application/json" --databinary '{
    "query": ca=node:emp(NUM_OFC_CA = {num_ofc_ca}) RETURN distinct ca.NME_CA as `CAName`",
    "params": {
        "num_ofc_ca": "997015"
    }
}'
```

For a general [lucene index query](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-start.html#start-node-by-index-query), you need to parametrize the full query:

```
curl -X POST http://<host>:7474/db/data/ext/CypherPlugin/graphdb/execute_query -H "Content-Type: application/json" --databinary '{
    "query": ca=node:emp({num_ofc_ca_query}) RETURN distinct ca.NME_CA as `CAName`",
    "params": {
        "num_ofc_ca_query": "NUM_OFC_CA:997015"
    }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas! Thanks a ton for suggesting a more general index query.