# Can you use parameters in a multi-index lookup cypher query passed over the REST API?

Tags: neo4j

I want to perform a Cypher query similar to:

```
START n=node:myindex('value:"hello" OR value:"world"') return n
```

Using the REST API, something like this works:

```
POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher {"query" : "start n = node:myindex('value=hello OR value=world') return n"}
```

*(from here on in, I'm going to strip the `POST <url>` bit and just past the JSON)*

What I'd like to do is parameterize the query so - ideally:

```
{
 "query" : "start n = node:myindex('value={p0} OR value={p1}') return n", 
 "params" : { "p0" : "hello", "p1" : "world"}
}
```

But that gives me:

```
400 Bad Request
{
  "exception" : "BadInputException",
  "fullname" : "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.BadInputException",
  "stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationExceptionHandlingIterable.exceptionOnHasNext(RepresentationExceptionHandlingIterable.java:50)", "org.neo4j.helpers.collection.ExceptionHandlingIterable$1.hasNext(ExceptionHandlingIterable.java:60)", "org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.hasNext(IteratorWrapper.java:42)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ListRepresentation.serialize(ListRepresentation.java:58)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:75)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingSerializer.putList(MappingSerializer.java:61)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.CypherResultRepresentation.serialize(CypherResultRepresentation.java:57)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingRepresentation.serialize(MappingRepresentation.java:42)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.assemble(OutputFormat.java:179)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.formatRepresentation(OutputFormat.java:131)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.response(OutputFormat.java:117)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.ok(OutputFormat.java:55)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CypherService.cypher(CypherService.java:95)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)" ],
  "cause" : {
    "exception" : "NullPointerException",
    "stacktrace" : [ "org.apache.lucene.util.SimpleStringInterner.intern(SimpleStringInterner.java:54)", "org.apache.lucene.util.StringHelper.intern(StringHelper.java:39)", "org.apache.lucene.index.Term.<init>(Term.java:38)", "org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.getFieldQuery(QueryParser.java:643)", "org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:1436)", "org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:1319)", "org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:1245)", "org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:1234)", "org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:206)", "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.IndexType.query(IndexType.java:300)", "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.query(LuceneIndex.java:227)", "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.query(LuceneIndex.java:238)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.gdsimpl.GDSBackedQueryContext$$anon$1.indexQuery(GDSBackedQueryContext.scala:87)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.IndexQueryBuilder$$anonfun$getNodeGetter$2.apply(IndexQueryBuilder.scala:83)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.IndexQueryBuilder$$anonfun$getNodeGetter$2.apply(IndexQueryBuilder.scala:81)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.StartPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(StartPipe.scala:36)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.StartPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(StartPipe.scala:35)", "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$hasNext$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ClosingIterator.scala:36)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$hasNext$1.apply(ClosingIterator.scala:35)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$hasNext$1.apply(ClosingIterator.scala:35)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.failIfThrows(ClosingIterator.scala:86)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.hasNext(ClosingIterator.scala:35)", "org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult.hasNext(PipeExecutionResult.scala:133)", "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)", "scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:29)", "org.neo4j.helpers.collection.ExceptionHandlingIterable$1.hasNext(ExceptionHandlingIterable.java:58)", "org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.hasNext(IteratorWrapper.java:42)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ListRepresentation.serialize(ListRepresentation.java:58)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:75)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingSerializer.putList(MappingSerializer.java:61)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.CypherResultRepresentation.serialize(CypherResultRepresentation.java:57)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingRepresentation.serialize(MappingRepresentation.java:42)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.assemble(OutputFormat.java:179)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.formatRepresentation(OutputFormat.java:131)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.response(OutputFormat.java:117)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.ok(OutputFormat.java:55)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CypherService.cypher(CypherService.java:95)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)" ],
    "fullname" : "java.lang.NullPointerException"
  }
}
```

Is there anyway to achieve this goal?

EDIT

For reference if I pass in:

```
{
 "query" : "start n = node:myindex('value=hello OR value=world') return n"
}
```

I get back results, I'm presuming the problem lies with the `'` surrounding the index query.

Comment: There's another question about [parametrizing index lookups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717225/index-parameterization-in-cypher-rest-query/16720980#16720980), does this fit your problem?

Comment: Nope, as that is for single parameters which works fine, this is specifically for multiple parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to parameterize parts of index query. In this case you have to use the whole index query as single parameter as Thomas pointed out in the 2nd snippet of [Index parameterization in Cypher REST query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717225/index-parameterization-in-cypher-rest-query/16720980#16720980)

Comment: I see, so parameterize the entire query, thank you for pointing out the solution in context - this is a case of not seeing the wood for the trees.